# Unity Lighting 2DDL InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am just new to unity and c# scripting language... i was just trying to make something in unity and was using 2DDL for lighting the problem i am getting is whenever i hit to play and test the game the light is following the gameobject correctly but after a while it's getting stuck at any random point... you can check the screenshot for the full error detail.

[image]

2DLight Script

```
void Update(){

        getAllMeshes();
        setLight ();
        renderLightMesh ();
        resetBounds ();

    }


    void getAllMeshes(){
        //allMeshes = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(PolygonCollider2D)) as PolygonCollider2D[];


        Collider2D [] allColl2D = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, lightRadius, layer);
        allMeshes = new PolygonCollider2D[allColl2D.Length];

        for (int i=0; i<allColl2D.Length; i++) {
            allMeshes[i] = (PolygonCollider2D)allColl2D[i];
        }



    }

    void resetBounds(){
        Bounds b = lightMesh.bounds;
        b.center = Vector3.zero;
        lightMesh.bounds = b;
    }
```

Comment: Double click on the error in the inspector, where does it take you? What code is there?  Who owns that code?

Comment: @Draco18s it points me to the 2Dlight(@DDL -> Radial Procedural Gradient) script. I am updating the script please check.

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily cast like that. What if the OverlapAll picks up a `BoxCollider2D`? A `BoxCollider2D` isn't a `PolygonCollider2D` but you're asking it to be.